# Programmatically apply an XSL transform outside the browser

Tags: xml, automation, python-3.x, xslt

I have XML data which I want to be able to display in a browser through an XSL Transform, and also compile with XeLaTeX. Inside the XML file, I have set the stylesheet to be the one for the browser, and currently, to get LaTeX output I have to go into the XML file, change that, open it in a browser, copy it into a file, save the file and run XeLaTeX against it.

Instead, I would like to leave the XML file associated with the XSLT stylesheet that transforms it to XHTML, and just have a build script that would:

1. Apply the LaTeX XSL transform file to the XML file, writing the result to a `.tex` file.
2. Run XeLaTeX against it.
3. Run XeLaTex against it again (the document requires second-pass).
4. Clean up log files, etc., unless instructed not to do so.

I know how to do #2-#4. What is the best way to accomplish #1? For example, is there a Python3 recipe for applying an XSL transform to an XML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your stylesheet written in the XSLT 1.0 you can use libxslt through [lxml](http://lxml.de/) (libxml2 & libxslt python bindings). Look for [lxml examples](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aOuH2umo-dtYJ%3alxml.de/xpathxslt.html&cd=2&hl=ru&ct=clnk) (link to google web cache, because actual page aren't available on the http://lxml.de)

Answer (score 1):

Following the lead given by @Phillip Kovalev, I have come up with this Python3 code:

```
from lxml import etree 
def transform(xsltpath:str, xmlpath:str):
    return etree.XSLT(etree.parse(xsltpath))(etree.parse(xmlpath))
def main():
    import sys
    print(transform(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Kudos to the developer of `lxml`--works like a charm!